# List<Objects> have different objects

Tags: java, list, object

```
Class A{
    Date createDate  
}

class B{
    Date createDate
}

class c{
    Date createDate
}

//Now im adding to list :
List<Object>list=new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm adding to the list, now i want to sort based on date, which has different objects. How to sort with different objects?

Comment: You should try this.
seems same to me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6171298/5610686

Answer (score 3):

you should make those classes implement a common interface with a method like;

```
Date getCreateDate();
```

and use that interface in your custom `Comparator` class.

Comment: This is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code apply your sorting algorithm to sort the date .
By this code you will be able to detect ,object belongs to which class.

```
     for(Object l1:list)
     {
      if((l1.getClass()).equals(A.class))//if object Is of class A
        {

        }
        else if((l1.getClass()).equals(B.class)) // if object Is of class B
        {

        }
        else //if object Is of class C
        {

        }

    }
```